# Find maximum sum subgrid under constraint

Tags: dynamic-programming

Give a positive $m$ by $n$ matrix as input, choose a set of elements such that for any 2 by 2 submatrices, at most 2 elements are chosen. Return the maximum sum of chosen elements among all possible choice.

For instance, for input [[1,3,4,3],[2,5,6,7]], the answer is 2 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 20.

I feel like this is a DP algorithm, but I don't know how to approach it. Any ideas? Feel like it's a DP problem.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/166843/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4872606/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).